# VBA GoTo application - how to put delay

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have a search text box which helps me to find cell with the text matching the letter I type in the box, is there a way to put delay on this search event because I am basically able to type only one letter and sometimes I would like to be able to type few more letters in the string before the search kicks in...

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal 
 Shift As Integer)

     On Error Resume Next
     Application.GoTo Range("A" & 
     Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox1.Value, Range("B2:B5000"), 
     1) + 1), True
     On Error GoTo 0

 End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using `TextBox1_BeforeUpdate` for your event handler?

Comment: It is above my abilities... I would need more help. :(

Comment: With `TextBox1_BeforeUpdate`, the code only gets triggered when you 1) press the Tab or ENTER key to get to the next control, or 2) click another control.  Also, when there's no match, the code can be written so that the textbox maintains focus, and the entered text highlighted to make re-entering a new value into the same textbox easier.  Would this work for you?  If so, when there's an error, do you want the textbox to maintain focus, and the text highlighted?

Comment: I guess after typing the letters and pressing the enter would be just fine...The main function of that box would be to find the first entry in the long alphabetical list of entries in excel, lets say instead of manually scrolling down the rows and finding first entry with text "Green" in column B , after entering in the text box first few letters in this case "Gre" it would automatically scroll down to the first entry starting with typed letters...

Comment: Actually, it looks like you may only need to change your current code so that Match searches for an exact match and the lookup value includes a wildcard `Application.GoTo Range("A" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox1.Value & "*", Range("B2:B5000"), 0) + 1), True`.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, this works very well. Thank you!